# How to count the xml node inside xml element using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to generate my HTML.

I am having below xml and I want to write condition if there is only one city node inside a country node I want to write some condition, please see the below xml.

There are two xmls.

1) destinations.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <list type="Destinations">
    <resources location="include/xml/locations.xml">
    <publication>232</publication>
    </resources>
    <destination id="594904" title="Maldives" url="/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives/maldives.aspx" thumbnail="/99/english/images/square_tcm481-594879.jpg" FeaturedDestination="true">        
    <city id="192513" />
    </destination>
    <destination id="594089" title="New Delhi" url="/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi.aspx" thumbnail="/99/english/images/sydney_tcm481-594346.jpg" FeaturedDestination="true" NewestDestination="true">        
    <city id="192460" />
    </destination>
    </list>
```

For eample In the above xml there is `city id = 192513` for maldives and it is alone node in locations.xml this will be checked in below locations.xml and if that id is alone in that country node then I need to call specific condition.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list type="Locations">
<region id="192393" code="ASIA" name="Asia &amp; the Pacific" shortname="Asia &amp; the Pacific">
<country id="192395" code="AU" name="Australia" shortname="Australia">
<city id="192397" code="BNE" name="Brisbane" shortname="Brisbane">
<airport id="192399" code="BNE" name="Brisbane International Airport" shortname="Brisbane"></airport>
</city>
<city id="192409" code="SYD" name="Sydney" shortname="Sydney">
<airport id="192411" code="SYD" name="Kingsford Smith Airport" shortname="Sydney"></airport>
</city>
</country>
<country id="192511" code="MV" name="Maldives" shortname="Maldives">
<city id="192513" code="MLE" name="Male" shortname="Male">
<airport id="192515" code="MLE" name="Male International Airport" shortname="Male"></airport>
</city>
</country>
</region>
</list>
```

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Comment: Good qyestion (+1). See my answer for a short one-liner XPath solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count($vLocations/*/*/country[city[@id = $vDestCity/@id]]/city) = 1
```

In this expression `$vLocations` is the XML document with top element `<list type="Locations">` and $vDestCity is the `<city>` element we are interested in from the XML document with top element `<list type="Destinations">`

**To see this in action**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:locations>
    <list type="Locations">
        <region id="192393" code="ASIA" 
                name="Asia &amp; the Pacific" 
                shortname="Asia &amp; the Pacific">
            <country id="192395" code="AU" name="Australia"
                               shortname="Australia">
                <city id="192397" code="BNE" name="Brisbane"
                                   shortname="Brisbane">
                    <airport id="192399" code="BNE"
                                          name="Brisbane International Airport"
                                          shortname="Brisbane">
                                        </airport>
                </city>
                <city id="192409" code="SYD" name="Sydney" 
                                   shortname="Sydney">
                    <airport id="192411" code="SYD"
                                         name="Kingsford Smith Airport"
                                         shortname="Sydney">
                                        </airport>
                </city>
            </country>
            <country id="192511" code="MV" name="Maldives"
                                shortname="Maldives">
                <city id="192513" code="MLE" name="Male"
                                     shortname="Male">
                    <airport id="192515" code="MLE" 
                                          name="Male International Airport"
                                          shortname="Male">
                                        </airport>
                </city>
            </country>
        </region>
    </list>
 </my:locations>

 <xsl:variable name="vLocations"
  select="document('')/*/my:locations"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDestCity1"
    select="/*/destination/city[@id=192513]"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDestCity2"
    select="/*/destination/city[@id=192397]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "count($vLocations/*/*/country
                [city[@id = $vDestCity1/@id]]/city
           ) = 1
    "/>
    :
<xsl:text/>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "count($vLocations/*/*/country
                [city[@id = $vDestCity2/@id]]/city
           ) = 1
    "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided** destinations.xml:

```
<list type="Destinations">
    <resources location="include/xml/locations.xml">
        <publication>232</publication>
    </resources>
    <destination id="594904" title="Maldives" url="/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives/maldives.aspx" thumbnail="/99/english/images/square_tcm481-594879.jpg" FeaturedDestination="true">
        <city id="192513" />
    </destination>
    <destination id="594089" title="New Delhi" url="/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi.aspx" thumbnail="/99/english/images/sydney_tcm481-594346.jpg" FeaturedDestination="true" NewestDestination="true">
        <city id="192460" />
    </destination>
</list>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
true
    :
false
```

Answer (score 0):

for example Australia: count(//country[@id='192395']/city)